# Looking for a plugin to refer all js files faster and easier to use

Tags: javascript

I'm working with multiple js file in my project. So, I'm looking for a plugin that I can refer any js file `fast and easy` (No need to install any compiler in the background).

Here is a corner:

[image: 1]

Normally, everytime I need to use it:

```
<script src="/path/app1.js"></script>
<script src="/path/app2.js"></script>
<script src="/path/app3.js"></script>
<script src="/path/app4.js"></script>
<script src="/path/app5.js"></script>
<script src="/path/app6.js"></script>
<script src="/path/app7.js"></script>
<script src="/path/app8.js"></script>
<script src="/path/app9.js"></script>
<script src="/path/app10.js"></script>
<!-- ... -->
```

So terrible ^^!

Then, I've tried to use google search and found [requirejs](http://requirejs.org/). But I doesn't be `faster` to use at all, because I need to config for every js file (object name and js path):

```
requirejs.config({
    baseUrl: 'js/lib',
    paths: {
        app1: 'app1-1.1.0',
        app2: 'app2-1.1.0',
        app3: 'app3-1.1.0',
        app4: 'app4-1.1.0',
        app5: 'app5-1.1.0',
        app6: 'app6-1.1.0',
        app7: 'app7-1.1.0',
        app8: 'app8-1.1.0',
        app9: 'app9-1.1.0',
        app10: 'app10-1.1.0'
        // ...
    }
});
```

So, what's happen if I have more than 50 js files? I must define 50 objects for 50 files. And after upgrading to new version, I must edit the file name in the configuration... blabla

Then, I've tried to search again and found another way. Using [import and export keywords](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/scripting/javascript/javascript-in-vs-2017). But it requires a compiler in the background, not a standard syntax.

I'm looking for a plugin like this:

```
// window.Animal is 'undefined' here

using('Animal'); // using is a global function while 'Animal' is a parameter

// window.Animal is an object here

class Cat extends Animal {
    constructor(name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    Speak() {
        return 'meow meow';
    }
};
```

Is there any plugin like that? Thank you!

Comment: Have you looked into using [babel](https://babeljs.io) and [webpack](https://webpack.js.org/) to bundle your javascript files into one?

Comment: Read about a bundler, like webpack or Babel, and about lazy loading. This way you can bundle your files and use just when you are going to use it.

Answer (score 0):

> I'm working with multiple js file in my project. So, I'm looking for a plugin that I can refer any js file fast and easy (No need to install any compiler in the background).

Consider using a module bundler such as [Webpack](https://webpack.github.io/) or [Browserify](http://browserify.org/). More or less performing the same function, these two package bundlers will allow you to use `CommonJS` modules in your code such as `var package = require('package')`.  When you run your "bundle" task either via webpack directly or via gulp or grunt in the case of browserify. The respective bundler will start with some entry point file that you provide and automatically create one 'bundle.js' that you can include as follows `<script src="/path/bundle.js"></script>`.

Here is a good place to start -> [Webpack Tutorial](https://medium.com/javascript-training/beginner-s-guide-to-webpack-b1f1a3638460)

Answer (score 0):

I have writed a simple function to generate code snippet from a directory's files. A modified version:

```
var fs = require('fs');

function getPathScripts(path) {
    var fnames,
        scripts;

    fnames = fs.readdirSync(path);

    console.log(fnames);
    // [ 'app1.js', 'app2.js', 'app3.css' ]

    scripts = fnames
        .filter(function (fname) {
            return fname.match(/.js$/); // add your filter condition
        })
        .map(function (fname) {
            return `<script src="${ path }/${ fname }"></script>`
        }).join('\n');

    console.log(scripts);
    //<script src="./path/app1.js"></script>
    //<script src="./path/app2.js"></script>

    return scripts;
}

var output = getPathScripts('./path');

fs.writeFileSync('output.js', output); // write content to a file
```